# Understanding .NET Application Memory Size

Tags: c#, .net, windows, memory, clr

An application I'm working on takes 338MB private bytes and 780MB virtual bytes right after startup.
I'm trying to understand what takes all this memory. Hopefully after understanding that I'll be able to reduce it's size.
This is a 32bit C# application, numbers above were taken while it is running in Windows7 64bit.

Opening a dump with windbg shows that the heap size is 47MB.
The total external library files size that the application is loading is 60MB.

An empty c# application takes only 10MB so what can cause my application to reach 338MB private bytes?
And why windows7 allocates 780MB virtual memory?

Any directions will help.

Comment: 1. Use a [memory profiler](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bc%23%5D+memory+profiler) to find out where your application allocates a lot of memory. 2. Have a look at the answer to [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/334179/whats-a-reasonable-amount-of-memory-for-a-net-application/334194#334194); maybe it answers already part of your question.

Comment: If it is the application that allocates the memory, am I not suppose to see it in the heap? The heep is only 47MB.

Comment: Is this causing an actual problem, or is this a matter of curiosity?

Comment: @John Saunders This is causing actual problem because the sizes I've wrote are the base sizes after launching the program but since this is a HD video streaming and rendering related application, memory goes up pretty quickly. Add to this that this is a 32bit application and the ~1.5GB virtual memory limit is reached too quickly.

Comment: @galbarm: and what, exactly, happens when the memory limit is reached?

Comment: @John Saunders Out Of Memory exceptions when trying to allocate objects.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can utilize [VMMap](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/dd535533), a process virtual and physical memory analysis utility
from [`Windows Sysinternals`](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals) on the technet site.

> `VMMap`shows a breakdown of a process's committed virtual memory types as well as the amount of physical memory (working set) assigned by the operating system to those types. Besides graphical representations of memory usage, VMMap also shows summary information and a detailed process memory map. Powerful filtering and refresh capabilities allow you to identify the sources of process memory usage and the memory cost of application features.
>
> Besides flexible views for analyzing live processes, VMMap supports the export of data in multiple forms, including a native format that preserves all the information so that you can load back in. It also includes command-line options that enable scripting scenarios.
>
> **VMMap is the ideal tool for developers wanting to understand and optimize their application's memory resource usage**.

Comment: Thanks. This is indeed a direction we're going now. The first thing we've noticed is that referenced assemblies were loaded twice. This is a known problem and was fixed in .net4 (see here: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/981266). After applying the hotfix, virtual memory size was reduced by 50MB which is a good start.